# Can't find wireless networks on Debian

Tags: wireless-networking, debian-squeeze

I am new to Debian (previously using Ubuntu, which is also Debian based). When I installed it on my Lenovo G450 laptop, I skipped the wireless configuration (I really didn't know how to do that).

After the installation, I found no wireless network available.

I add

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

to `/etc/network/interface`, then typed

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

But the terminal told me that "interface not support for this operation".

Anyway I tried

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid xxx key xxx
```

and the terminal said: "invalid argument".

Can anyone help? I had to turn to Fedora/Ubuntu again. They have `network-manager` to configure the wireless network, but Debian does not. I wanted to install `network-manager`, but I can't connect to the internet.

Comment: I fixed your formatting – please use the syntax and editor help if you're not sure. There's no need for `<br>`. — As for your question: Are you sure you added it to `/etc/network/interfaces` and not `interface` (notice the missing "s")? Have you  done a `/etc/init.d/networking restart` after editing the interfaces? And "interface not support … " – are you sure this is the **exact** error message you get?

Comment: Read the [Debian manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/reference/ch05.en.html#_the_basic_syntax_of_etc_network_interfaces): `/etc/network/interfaces` needs an `iface`, **not** ´interface` line where you put the `wlan0`.

Comment: I think i found the reason, it does not have the wireless firmware of the old broadcom network device.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well you could write an answer to your own question if you found out how to get it working!

Comment: In many devices you have to install dkms from either APT repo or by manually .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just because the lack of the old broadcom wireless driver. i download b43 and compile it.

> this link will help [install b43 firmware](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Download#Building_and_installing)

the new 3.x kernel seems have broadcom firmware built in

Comment: Ah, the ol' `download and compile vendor specific driver` trick! If we can raise awareness about this technique, it'll be the year of Linux on the desktop in no time!

Comment: very sorry! I add a link from the b43 project site.